# Why does Active Directory when clicking on a group no users displayed, but users are assigned to the group

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Prior to yesterday when I selected a group in AD on the right panel all users in that group appeared, now Active Directory when clicking on a group no users displayed, but users are assigned to the group.

Any help much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you click on an OU, as a group is still an object in AD...

Comment: Hi Chris,  Yes the OU has users and groups, the users are there and have been added to the groups, but in the console if I highlight the group no users are shown on the right hand panel.

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot of what you see

Comment: I am a novice, how do i add the screen shot, sorry Chris

Comment: Whilst editing your question there is a "picture" button where you can upload a picture from your computer. This will put the picture into your question./

Comment: Added to first question, you'll see all the users on the left under users, 3 of these are in the group Ascarii_StandardAccess but they are not shown on the right hand panel

Comment: I'm out of ideas.. I've exhausted my MMC (with ADUC snap-in loaded) and I cannot get group members to show. The view you have is to view users, groups, contacts and computers as containers from the drop-down in MMC.

Answer (score 0):

You may have inadvertently set a filter on your MMC view.

1. Click **View** at top of MMC
2. Click **Filter Options...**
3. Select the **Show all types of objects** radio button
4. Click **OK**

You should now see all object types in any OU you select.

Comment: Tried that one, sorry filter shows all